# Compound of two exponential distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the distribution of a exponential distribution, whose expected values is drawn from the expontial distribution

$$X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\text{mean}=\alpha)  f(x\mid α) = (1/α) \exp(-x/α) $$

$$Y\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\text{mean}=X)  f(y\mid x) = (1/x) \exp(-y/x) $$

how is $Y$ distributed?

I have found this question answered when $X$ and $Y$ are parameterized in terms of rates (Pareto), but I can't figure it out when $X$ and $Y$ are parameterized in terms of expected values.

Comment: Since the expected value is the reciprocal of the rate, can't you just find the rates and use the solution you got for those? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  If I let Z=1/X, then I have Y parameterized in terms of its rate, f(y|z) = z exp(-yz), and Z follows an inverse exponential distribution, f(z|α) = exp(-1/zα)/z**2.  Now I need to integrate exp(-yz) exp(-1/zα) / z with respect to Z.  Is that an easy one?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to find the distribution of $Y$ where $Y\mid X=x\sim \mathrm{Exp}\left(\frac1x\right)$. To find the marginal density of $Y$ given the marginal density of $X$ and conditional density of $Y$ given $X$, we would compute

\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathsf dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)\mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac1xe^{-\frac 1xy}\frac1\alpha e^{-\frac1\alpha x}\mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac1{\alpha x} e^{-\left(\frac yx+\frac x\alpha\right)}\mathsf dx,
\end{align}
but this integral can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions (please correct me if I'm wrong). On the other hand, if we have $X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(\alpha)$ and $Y\mid X\sim\mathrm{Exp}(X)$ then with a straightforward application of integration by parts we obtain
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty xe^{-xy}\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\mathsf dx = \int_0^\infty \alpha xe^{-x(\alpha+y)}\mathsf dx = \frac\alpha{(\alpha + y)^2}.$$

(This doesn't exactly answer the question, but it is too long for a comment.)

Comment: hi.   You have it exactly right.  Sounds like you are saying that you don't think there is a closed-form solution to this question.   I was hoping that isn't the case, but I couldn't find one either.